# CodeIgniter Active Record multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to convert this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 = 'example' AND (date1 = 'date' OR renewal1 = 'renewal');
```

into CodeIgniter's Active Record format.  I tried the following:

```
$q = $this->db->select('*');
$q = $this->db->from('table');
$q = $this->db->where('condition1 = condition');
$q = $this->db->where('date1 = date OR renewal = renewal');
$q = $this->db->get();
$results = $q->result();
```

But this did not have the desired affect.  It seemed to not place the parenthesis around the second set of conditions, which caused the query to not work as expected.  How else can I do this to represent what I want?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('condition1 =',' condition');
$where = '(date1 = "date" OR renewal1 = "renewal")';// you can use your condition like this
$this->db->where($where);
$q = $this->db->get();
$results = $q->result();
```

Comment: will this separate the last two conditions from the first so that they run together as a block?  If that makes sense...

Comment: check updated answer . it will separate you condition